# Node server config file : serve files from 2 directories

Tags: node.js, server, directory, readfile

I want to learn to setup a node server without Express.js.

**My server config file works fine** but the way I found to serve files from two different folders is a hack (see comments):

```js
const http       = require("http");
const url        = require("url");
const filesystem = require("fs");
const lookup     = require("mime-types").lookup;

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    let parsedURL = url.parse(req.url,true);
    let path      = parsedURL.path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, "");
    if (path == ""){path =  "index.html";}

    // I need to authorize the files from those 2 directories:
    
    let file1 = __dirname + "/public/"       + path;
    let file2 = __dirname + "/node_modules/" + path;

    filesystem.readFile(file1,function(err,content){

        if(err){

            // the second readfile inside the error condition of 
            // the first read file is meh...

            filesystem.readFile(file2,function(err,content){
    
                if(err){
        
                    console.log("File not found: " + file2);
                    res.writeHead(404);
                    res.end();
        
                }
                else{
        
                    let mime = lookup(path);
                    console.log("Retrieving: " + file2);
                    res.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options","nosniff");
                    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": mime});
                    res.end(content);
        
                }
        
            })

        }
        else{

            let mime = lookup(path);
            console.log("Retrieving: " + file1);
            res.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options","nosniff");
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": mime});
            res.end(content);

        }

    })

});

server.listen(1234, "localhost", function(){
    console.log("Server started at port 1234"); 
});
```

Is there a way to make the handling of 2 different directories less awkward (one as an error response of the other + repeating identical code is anything but elegant or optimal)?

Thanks.